# Difference in data shown via the web browser on PC and IPhone

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

My answer to this question [NullReferenceException was unhandled #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178759/c-sharp-nullreferenceexception-was-unhandled/10178908#10178908)

shows as being accepted then unacepted when I browse on the IPhone. That information does not show up when I browse using IE on a PC.

Note: Justin had a better answer, so I am not complaining about the unaccept.

Comment: Could this be a caching issue?

Comment: Where are you looking to see whether it's shown? The reputation listed in your profile?

Comment: Yes, reputation list on profile

Comment: We can repro - the mobile view is showing votes that were cast and quickly retracted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mobile view *should* have been filtering these, but goes through a bit of a different code path.

It'll be fixed in the next build.